# Can you set the size of the call stack in c++? (vs2008)

Tags: c++, callstack

I'm working from an example piece of code that allocates a relatively large local array. (32768 to be precise) When I try the same I'm getting behaviour that appears to be a stack overflow. Now I was wondering if my example has maybe set the stack to be larger then my application. Is this possible? if so how?

Comment: Just a point on Semantics, "call stack" usually refers to the list of functions that make up the context for a function call.  The memory valid for the context of a call is simply the stack.

Comment: Actually, the term 'stack' is an outdated term. 'Call stack' encompasses the entire context of the current call (ie local variables and parameters) see http://www.programmingforums.org/thread8786.html#9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Microsoft compiler you can use [/F](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-160) to set the stack size, however it seems like you should just allocate the object on the heap.  You should have a reason you're allocating this on the stack rather than the heap.

Edit: [This page](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) gives a good cross-platform breakdown, though it may be dated.

Comment: This is was very helpful, although it didn't fix the problem. Further investigation needed :(

Comment: Maybe you should post a sample of your code in a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614842/why-does-this-code-corrupt-memory, already answered but setting the stack size hasn't fixed the problem so your thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /F compiler flag to set the default stack size, or specify it as the second parameter to the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with with the stack size, why don't you simply use a std::vector or even dynamically allocate an array yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new thread for this work. You can generally specify the size of the stack when creating a thread, and certainly with vs2008's `CreateThread()` function