# C++ Change Max RAM Limit

Tags: c++, c, unix, memory-limit

How would I change the max amount of RAM for a program? I constantly am running out of memory (not system max, ulimit max), and I do not wish to change the global memory limit. I looked around and saw the vlimit() function might work, but I'm unsure exactly how to use it.

Edit: I'm on linux 2.6.38-11-generic
This is not a memory leak, I literally must allocate 100k of a given class, no way around it.

Comment: you need to specify exactly what limit you are running into before we can start guessing how to lift the limit

Comment: Why would 100k objects result in out of memory? How big is each object? Are you perhaps in a 32 bit process and its address space rather than memory that is the limit?

Comment: @Precursor: How much memory is the program using when it "runs out"?  How much RAM/swap do you have?  Is the program 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 100k objects at 10kb each is still only 1gig. What is your limit set to? How much RAM do you have? and how big are these objects?

Answer (score 3):

Do you allocate the objects on the stack and are in fact hitting the stack limit?

Do you, e.g., write something like this:

```
void SomeFunction() {
    MyObject aobject[100000];
    // do something with myobject
}
```

This array will be allocated on the stack. A better solution -- which automates heap allocation for you -- would be to write

```
void SomeFunction() {
    std::vector<MyObject> veccobject(100000); // 100.000 default constructed objects
    // do something with myobject
}
```

If for some reason, you really want a bigger stack, consult your compiler documentation for the appropriate flag:

[How to increase the gcc executable stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156783/how-to-increase-the-gcc-executable-stack-size)

[Can you set the size of the call stack in c++? (vs2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625416/can-you-set-the-size-of-the-call-stack-in-c-vs2008)

And you might want to consider:

[When do you worry about stack size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915900/when-do-you-worry-about-stack-size)

Answer (score 2):

If these limits are being imposed on you by the system administrator, then no - you're stuck. If you're `ulimit`ing yourself, sure - just raise the soft and hard limits.

As pointed out by Chris in the comments, if you're a privileged process, you could use [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to raise your hard limit in process. However, one presumes if you're under a `ulimit`, then you're unlikely to be a privileged process.

Comment: Well, I am the system administrator. But the thing is, I don't really want to use the ulimit command on linux to change it globally. Is there some way I can do this from code?

Comment: You can use the `ulimit` command only inside a single shell, i.e. inside a single terminal.

Comment: You could launch through a shell that isn't under the limit. But there's no userland API to bypass it (it would be a bit useless if any application not wanting to be limited could just "opt out").

Comment: @Adam: there is a userland API -- `setrlimit(2)`.  The ulimit command is basically just a trivial wrapper around setrlimit.  Of course, you may get EPERM errors if you don't have permission.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Ah, my mistake. Though my main point stands - non privileged processes can't change their hard limit upwards.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand **why you are hitting the RAM limit?** Are you sure that you don't have **memory leaks** (if you do have leaks, you'll need more and more RAM when running your application for a longer time).

Assuming a Linux machine, you might use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt and debug memory leaks, and you could also use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) to often avoid them.

Comment: This isn't a memory leak. I must allocate around 100,000 instances of a class, hence the fact I am running out of memory.

Comment: Then the solution is either to buy some more RAM (which is cheap today), or lower the number of instances, or decrease the size of each instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions you can use the [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) call (which supersedes vlimit) to set the limits at the start of your program. This will only affect this program and its offspring.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main() {
  struct rlimit limit;
  limit.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
  limit.rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY;
  if (0 != setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit)) {
  //errro
  } 
}
```