# Limit Memory allocation to a process in Mac-OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, memory, memory-management

I would like to control the maximum memory, a process can use in Mac-OS X 10.8. I feel that setting ulimit -v should achieve the goals but doesn't seem to be the case. I tried following simple commands :

```
    ulimit -m 512

    java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m SomeJavaProgram
```

I was assuming that 2nd command should fail as Java Process will start by keeping 1024MB of memory for itself but it passes peacefully. Inside my Sample program, I try allocating more than 1024MB using following code snippet:

```
System.out.println("Allocating 1 GB of Memory");
List<byte[]> list = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
list.add(new byte[1073741824]); //1024 MB
System.out.println("Done....");
```

Both these programs get executed without any issues. How can we control the max memory allocation for a program in Mac-OS X?

Comment: Narinder Kumar, try to write something into your allocated data, at least one write per 4096 bytes, and check, will the ulimit limit new test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit memory of a OS X program? ulimit -v neither -m are working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274385/how-to-limit-memory-of-a-os-x-program-ulimit-v-neither-m-are-working)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if you still need the question answered, but here is the answer in case anyone else happens to have the same question.

`ulimit -m` strictly limits resident memory, and not the amount of memory a process can request from the operating system.

`ulimit -v` will limit the amount of virtual memory a process can request from the operating system.

for example...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int size = 1 << 20;

    void* memory = NULL;

    memory = malloc(size);

    printf("allocated %i bytes...\n", size);

    return 0; 

}
```

```
ulimit -m 512
./memory
allocated 1048576 bytes...
```

```
ulimit -v 512
./memory
Segmentation fault
```

If you execute `ulimit -a` it should provide a summary of all the current limits for child processes.

As mentioned in comments below by @bikram990, the [java](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/troubleshootingjava/entry/ulimit_and_xmx?lang=en) process may not observe soft limits.  To enforce java memory restrictions, you can pass arguments to the process (-Xmx, -Xss, etc...).

**Warning!**

You can also set hard limits via the `ulimit -H` [command](http://ss64.com/osx/ulimit.html), which cannot be modified by sub-processes.  However, those limits also cannot be raised again once lowered, without elevated permissions (root).

Comment: This works great on Linux, but does not work for OSX, which was the reason I was supporting the question with a bounty. Thanks for providing the code to reproduce though.

Comment: `ulimit` behavior is generally governed by POSIX, and OSX is POSIX compliant so I'm somewhat shocked.  The example specifies `ulimit -m` which won't affect limits on total virtual memory size.  I would be curious what `ulimit -a` actually reports.

Comment: pelson> ulimit -v 512
pelson> ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 512
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 512

Comment: Odd, it seems to report the correct virtual memory limit, 512k.  If you try executing `for ((i=0;i<1<<20;i++)); do m+='x'; done` after `ulimit -v 512`, what happens?  `unset m` will free the memory.

Comment: @Jason pelson is trying this on a java process. I think java may be modifying the hard limits for memory. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997602/c-change-max-ram-limit

Comment: @bikram990 Java compiles and executes on the fly, so that might explain why the reported limits aren't being adhered to.

Comment: @Jason See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/troubleshootingjava/entry/ulimit_and_xmx?lang=en
i.e. why its not using ulimit.

Comment: @Jason our interpretation was correct. java is changing the limits.

Comment: @bikram990 So, it looks like limits should be explicitly set for java processes via arguments (`-Xmx`, `-Xss`)?

Comment: @Jason `sudo ulimit -H -v 512` or `sudo ulimit -H -m 512` will set the hard limit and java will not be able to increase it. That way the limits can be enforced.

Comment: @bikram990 I don't think a process needs elevated permissions to lower it's hard limit via [ulimit](http://ss64.com/osx/ulimit.html), but once the hard limit is set it can't be raised without elevated permissions. So, for java, specifying the limits to the process is probably the safest thing to do.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not working with Java (though the original question did). @Jason's C example demonstrates the problem nicely IMHO and this is more to do with OSX than the Java VM.

Comment: memory limits OS X doesn't work using ulimit neither the corresponding system call. Using launchd was suggested by I haven't tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274385/how-to-limit-memory-of-a-os-x-program-ulimit-v-neither-m-are-working

Comment: In macOS setrlimit(2), RLIMIT_AS is an alias for RLIMIT_RSS. So no, the macOS kernel apparently doesn't support limiting a process' virtual memory usage, regardless which approach (ulimit or launchd) you use: all of these are based on setrlimit(2) in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, the manpage for ulimit (e.g. `man 3 ulimit`) says the following:

```
The ulimit() function will get and set process limits.  Currently, this is limited to the maximum file size.
```

The is from the `ulimit(3)` manual/manpage that comes bundled with macOS and it is dated January 4, 2003.

As for the `ulimit` builtin shell command, it is likely that all this is is a wrapper around the `ulimit()` C function. Therefore, it does not appear to be possible to set memory limits with `ulimit` on macOS. Perhaps try using the `setrlimit()` C function instead.

The only other thing I'm aware of is that it is possible to set/specify process limits for agents and daemons (see `man launchd.plist`).