# error while declaring double array of size 150000?

Tags: c++

I am developing a code in which there is need for declaring array of double of size 150000 and when one array is declared code is running successfully.if we declare two arrays then while execution it terminates throwing exception.

```
Code is :

double a[150000];
double b[150000];
```

if we declare a only then it executes perfectly.if declare both a and b then it terminates.
Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Stackoverflow, right? Give the arrays static storage or use a `std::vector`.

Comment: If you declare these arrays locally in a function, they are over 2MB of stack space. On Windows the default stack size is only 1MB.

Comment: Assuming these indeed are local variables, the space needed is 2 * 8 * 150000 (on x86), which is around 2.2 MB. Many operating systems limit the maximum stack of a process to less than that.

Comment: Make them float arrays.  Problem solved!

Comment: @HotLicks - problem solved, but new problem introduced!

Comment: Alernatively, just up the stack size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two arrays are [overflowing the stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) (assuming they are local variables). Dynamically allocate memory for the arrays instead, using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to manage the memory for you:

```
std::vector<double> a(150000);
std::vector<double> b(150000);
```

Even though the `std::vector` instances are on the stack, the `std::vector` dynamically allocates memory internally for the data which is on the heap, avoiding the stack overflow.

Comment: This is good, but worth mentioning that in C++03 it's unavoidably slower initially as all elements are written to when the vector is created.

Comment: @TonyD: That is just 2M of data, the cost of initialization is most probably negligible. If that is an issue, there are alternatives, but most probably the arrays are meant to be used, in which case most of the cost of initialization (actually touching the memory addresses) have to be paid anyways...

Answer (score 4):

Okay! You have [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) in your app!
[image]

Fixing examples:

- don't use stack - use [dynamic memory allocation (heap)](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/):

  `double* a = new double[150000];`
- use STL container, for example, [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) - internally it allocates things on heap

  `std::vector<double> a(150000);`
- increase stack size (bad idea, but if you really need it read you compiler docs, and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625416/can-you-set-the-size-of-the-call-stack-in-c-vs2008))
- redesign you code somehow

Comment: Don't use dynamic memory allocation like that. Use `<vector>` or at least `make_shared` or `make_unique`.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz Well, `<vector>` is ok, but `<unique_ptr>` and `<shared_ptr>` is completly wrong here: they will leak, because of using `delete` operator instead of `delete []`

Comment: You can safely use `unique_ptr<T[]>`, and it will call `delete[]`. You might want to update your knowledge about smart pointers.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz Whoops! Looks like my ancient brain is a little out of date. So <unique_ptr> have template specialization for arrays. And what about <shared_ptr>?

Comment: for `shared_ptr` you need your own deleter. Still no leak.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz "Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array." http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm

Comment: @IgorR. Let's hope it appears in C++14/17 then.

Answer (score 2):

There is one solution to this problem, but it leads to (at least) three different follow-on solutions. The solution is "don't use large arrays as local variables, because it blows up the stack".

The solution clearly means changing the code in some way. There are a few different ways to do that.

The obvious and straight-forwards solution is to use `std::vector<double>` instead.

Another solution is to use `

```
unique_ptr<double[]> a = std::unique_ptr<double[]>(new double[150000]);
```

The third, and SOMETIMES a good solutions, is to make `a` and `b` global variables.

There are several other variants, but they are generally variations on the same theme, just with slight variations. What is best in your case really depends on what the rest of your code is doing. I'd start with `std::vector<double>`, but other alternatives do exist, should that be an unsuitable solution for some reason.

Comment: `<unique_ptr>` will leak, because of using `delete` operator instead of `delete []`

Comment: I've just edited in the missing space, which shows the extra `[]` that I believe will solve that problem, no?

Comment: Forget it =) 5 min ago I find out that `<unique_ptr>` has template specialization for arrays, with right deleter. Nice, huh?